# File interaction on harddrive takes a while to respond

Tags: windows-10

When I attempt to move/delete a file/files inside my hard drive, it's taking a minute or two to respond. An example would be moving a download that was placed in the wrong folder to the correct one and it not doing it instantaneously or providing a window showing how long it will take. I also deleted some files as well and it took it a moment to respond and show the *confirm* window. Any idea what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Alot of  things affect the system performance , things you could try

- Check HDD smart attributes (Old HDD maybe worn and about to go out) -> check smart attributes using crystal disk program or https://www.hdsentinel.com/.(anything that is a warning in the attributes needs attention ,  you should backup your data now).
- Filled up HDD (When  HDD gets full they slow down due to physical constraints)
- You may have a virus/malware on your  pc , run antivirus scan -> programs to scan :avira,avast/malwarebytes/bit defender,etc choose one.
- Motherboard chipset may be going out causing disk io timeouts
- Check sata/ide cable to HDD
- Check power to your system using a Digital Multi Meter/Oscilloscope on the atx connector (check atx pinout / 12v sata/molex pin out) , dirty power can cause system instability.
- Damaged file structure , run chkdsk /f on your hdd to repair errors

Answer (score 0):

Next time you do an operation, have Task Manager opened (right click the taskbar, select Task Manager) and select Performance.  Check the operation and see if CPU, memory, or hard drive are maxing out.  For CPU and memory bottlenecks, click on the Task Manager's Process tab, and click the column for CPU (if CPU is maxing out) or for memory (if memory is maxing out) to sort highest usage to lowest.  Identify what process(es) are taking up CPU/memory and kill them (if safe to do so) or find out what's calling them.

If the disk was maxing out, back on the Performance tab, click the "Open Resource Monitor" link at the bottom.  Make sure the "Disk" option is expanded.  Alternate clicking on the Read, Write, and Total... columns to sort by biggest to lowest usage to see what might be taking up the disk i/o bandwidth.  Kill that process, if safe to do so, or find out what is calling it and why.

Other possibilities include fragmented disk (if using a traditional HDD).  If using HDD (not an SSD, ** DON'T DEFRAG YOUR SSD **) try disk defrag to see if it's severely fragmented (Open up My computer (aka file Explorer or [Windows] + [E] key, right click on the drive and select properties, and go to tools.  Select the option to Optimize.  Select the drive in the list and click analyze.  If it says defrag not necessary, then fragmentation is not an issue

Next, if defrag wasn't the issue, return to the drive properties window > tools tab and run and select "Scan Drive" even if it says you don't need to.  See what is returns (if any problems and fix them if it gives you the option).

If still no issues, the last part would be to download the manufacturers tool box for the drive (Western Digital/Hitatchi use Data Life Guard - https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en&p=3 --- Seagate uses Seatools -- https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/)
...Run the corresponding utility for your drive, whoever makes it.  Do a short test and see if it passes.  If it does, do a long test (make sure you save any work that's open, and do it when you can walk away for a few hours).  A 4TB 7200 RPM drive will take about 6 hours to scan (just as a reference).  My 5900RPM 14TB took about a day to scan (I always scan them before I put them into operation).

#### SSD

If you are using an SSD, download the manufacturer's tool box for the SSD, and have it run diagnostics on the drive, though the kind of lag you describe I've never seen on an SSD - they either work, or they're toast...

Side note...  I have seen something like this once before when someone installed a cloud backup service.  They noticed a similar issue occurring everyday at the same time (around 4PM) that coincided with their backup schedule.  When they moved the backup further after hours, the problem while they worked, went away.

Best of luck